# How do Adepts, mechanically, function?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun

This question is looking for a clear summary that leans towards conciseness, and hopefully page numbers in the core rulebook.

I just joined a brand new group for Shadowrun 5e, and I'm fairly certain (from an in-story perspective) I wish to play an Adept, but I don't mechanically *get* Adepts; there's summary of them near the start of the character creation chapter, but it doesn't dip into mechanics, and the referenced page numbers are discussing references to what they *can't* do.

The players and GM are all trying to work the system out collectively; we have no expert.

I realize builds are more nebulous than are often found in tabletops (like most editions of D&D and classes), which I believe is why I can't find a section in the book that explains the mechanics of Adepts. Still hunting it seems like I'd find a better section than what I found at the beginning of the character creation chapter.

Mechanically (focused on character creation) what is the foundation of Adepts, and where do I find the *actual rules* and written considerations about Adepts?

Comment: A _very_ general view can be, that instead of spending money and essence for Cyber– and / or Bioware, you spent **Power Points** for similar things ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's presume that you've seen the summary on page 69 that shows the distinctions between the different kinds of magic using characters in Shadowrun 5E. The mechanical foundation of adepts is that they spend Power Points to purchase Powers that give them inherent supernatural ability. They start with a number of Power Points equal to their Magic rating. The section of Powers you can buy starts on page 308. They do what the descriptions say they do; they tend to be in the category of personal enhancements or mythic martial artistry.